# python: Threading issues while backporting to v2.4 from v2.7

Tags: python, multithreading

I had the following code that works fine with python 2.7+

```
class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
                 args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None, onCompleteCb=None):
        self.__onCompleteCb = onCompleteCb
        self.__name = name
        super(Worker, self).__init__(group, target, name, args, kwargs, verbose)

    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def run(self):
        try:
            super(Worker, self).run()
            if self.__onCompleteCb is not None: self.__onCompleteCb(self.__name)
        except Exception, e:
            if self.__onCompleteCb is not None: self.__onCompleteCb(self.__name, failed=True, exception=e)
```

But I found out recently my code should support versions starting from 2.4: In the above code, run gets called but when it calls `super(Worker, self).run()`, I see the following error

```
 TypeError: threadTargMethod() argument after ** must be a dictionary
```

Should I call `super` differently in python 2.4?

**Solution** 
I have to start the thread in the following way:

```
Worker(target=threadTargMethod, name="thread1", args=(), kwargs={}).start()
```

In v2.7 I was starting the following way and it works

```
Worker(target=threadTargMethod, name="thread1").start()
```

Comment: Are you sure it exits with no errors? I can definitely seeing it error out if `threading.Thread` was not a new-style class in 2.4

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, there is an error. By mistake logger.exception(e) go deleted in the except block. Updating the question with the error.

Comment: Seems like a very weird error. `threadTargMethod()` doesn't show up anywhere on google.

Comment: You might want to post your solution as an answer and accept it, that way the question stops being marked as "Unanswered" and if anybody happens to fall on it from google it'll be obvious it's solved and how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing your code to:

```
class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None,
             args=(), kwargs={}, verbose=None, onCompleteCb=None):
        ...
        super(Worker, self).__init__(group=group, target=target, name=name, 
                                     args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
```

In other words:

- Make the default for `kwargs` an empty dict (which matches the docs - you seem to have got lucky with 2.7)
- Don't include the `verbose` parameter (not supported in 2.4 or 2.7 - no idea what was happening there)
- Make names explicit

With that change you can continue to start with

```
Worker(target=threadTargMethod, name="thread1").start()
```

because `kwargs` will be set correctly by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have to start the thread in the following way in v2.4:

```
Worker(target=threadTargMethod, name="thread1", args=(), kwargs={}).start()
```

In v2.7 I was starting the following way and it works

```
Worker(target=threadTargMethod, name="thread1").start()
```